# WinAppDriver with Python problems

Tags: python-3.x, winappdriver

Overall my problem is I am trying to automate a Windows 10 application with WinnAppDriver and writing my automation in Python.  There seems to be very little information on how to do this as most WinAppDriver examples are in Java (understandable...).  But I BARELY know the basics of Python and nothing about Java.  So...is there a book or video I'm missing?  Specifically I installed everything (Python via VS Code) and actually got the Python sample Calculator test to run....then I had to restart my PC and I get the following error:

I apologize for being such a newbie....  I had learned basics of Python via videos so I could implement Sikulix automations and this worked great until I had to switch between computers....it is exceedingly easy to break Sikulix as it is resolution dependent.  So...after looking around I decided to try to automate via WinAppDriver...within Python.  Wow....I cannot find ANY books or videos on how to do this (since I barely am learning Python and know zero Java).  Any help would be appreciated and I WILL prove I will spend the time to watch recommended videos or study recommended books / texts.  Thanks so much in advance...

[Running] python -u "c:\Users\bartc\Downloads\WinAppDriver-master\WinAppDriver-master\Samples\Python\CasaCharm 1.py"
ERROR

======================================================================

### ERROR: setUpClass (**main**.SimpleCalculatorTests)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 355, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 183, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: : Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\bartc\Downloads\WinAppDriver-master\WinAppDriver-master\Samples\Python\CasaCharm 1.py", line 31, in setUpClass
    desired_capabilities= desired_caps)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 144, in **init**
    proxy
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in **init**
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 219, in start_session
    response = self.execute(RemoteCommand.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 397, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 72, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 150, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 326, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\bartc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4723): Max retries exceeded with url: /session (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

---

Ran 0 tests in 6.470s

FAILED (errors=1)

[Done] exited with code=0 in 22.349 seconds

Comment: Ugh....  OK.  So...after being stuck for three nights I finally figured out why the Python Calculator test was NOT running....: You have to actually run the WinAppDriver.exe so it is 'listening'....  What an embarrassing first question.  OK.  IF any of you have ANY suggestions on where to look for additional instruction / examples of automating Windows 10 Applications via Python and WinAppDriver...please forward...as I am still only finding examples of how to employ WinAppDriver via Java....  ( yes I understand it is written in Java, but supposedly you can control the automations with Python).

Comment: We all go through such mistakes, don't worry ;-). Is coding your scripts in Python a prerequisite? Since you're still learning python, maybe it's better to consider a language where winappdriver is documented more thoroughly?  I'm doing my ui test scripts in C#. Since C#, .net framework, winappdriver and VS Code are Microsoft products, it made more sense to me. It's just a suggestion based on personal opinion though :-). I would also suggest to first learn the basics of the language of your choosing before moving on to winappdriver.

Answer (score 1):

My company uses RobotFramework for automation testing which is built on top of python so I understand your pain on finding examples. I built out a testing library for Desktop automation using winappdriver and seeing as this is built on top of python [you may find the source code useful](https://github.com/Accruent/robotframework-zoomba/blob/master/src/Zoomba/DesktopLibrary.py)

The library extends [robotframework-appiumlibrary](https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary) for many of the base functionalities so their source code may be of use to you as well.

Alternatively if you are not well versed in python it may be worth looking into [robotframework](https://robotframework.org) and use the zoomba library I provided. Robotframework is very easy to pick up without any python knowledge.